# Can't make the timer decrease more then once

Tags: python, timer

I am trying to create a timer, which right now looks like this:

```
    #Timer 60 sec.
import time
sec = 60
def updateTimer():
    trecker.config(text = sec-1)
    trecker.after(1000, updateTimer)

trecker = Label(gui, text = sec)
trecker.place(x=500, y=200)
trecker.after(1000, updateTimer)
```

And the reason I write here is that it displays `60`, changes to `59` and then stops. I tried to loop it with for in range, but it doesn't help. My idea right now, is that it calls for `updateTimer`
function in the inside of its execution restarting itself. But it, for some reason does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sec-1` is just always `59` because `60-1=59`. Instead write:

```
def updateTimer():
    sec -= 1
    trecker.config(text = sec)
    trecker.after(1000, updateTimer)
```

Comment: ohhhh, I thought it would minus one every time. Thanks!